# Will Dns.GetHostEntry("LocalHost").HostName ever be null

Tags: c#, dns

If there is a Fully Qualified Domain Name ie `computername.domain.com`, if there isn't one, then the IP of the localhost.

If I use `Dns.GetHostEntry("LocalHost").HostName`, will it always return one of the above, or can it sometimes return null?

I will be using this code on a server machine, so there will be a network card.

Should I use an alternative to "HostName"?

Comment: What happens if there are no network cards?

Comment: localhost should always exist and will likely break things if it does not